# What could cause a wait cursor to revert to default before it should?

Tags: c#, cursor

In a Winforms app, I set the Cursor to WaitCursor and, in a finally block, set it back to Default:

```
private void buttonGenRpts_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        buttonGenRpts.Enabled = false;
        GenerateReports();
        ... // code elided for brevity (and hopefully not levity)
    }
    finally
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        buttonGenRpts.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

In most cases it works fine, but not all - the Cursor for some reason stops hourglassing. Yet Cursor is not set (to Default or anything else) anywhere else in the code - only in the code above.

Is there anything else that might cause the Cursor to start cursing its endless vibrating and cease with its coursing?

Comment: _Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor_ ?

Comment: Is that the preferred methodology? If so, why does it work at all without the ".Current"? I'll try it and see...

Comment: Setting it to Current made it die almost immediately.

Comment: VS says there is no Default property of Cursors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the current cursor for the whole application you should use

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
...
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
```

instead your code sets the Cursor property of the current form.
Probably you move your mouse outside the form bounds and it reverts back to its default.

[From MSDN Cursor class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor(v=vs.110).aspx)

> All controls that derive from the Control class have a Cursor
>   property. To change the cursor displayed by the mouse pointer when it
>   is within the bounds of the control, assign a Cursor to the Cursor
>   property of the control. Alternatively, you can display cursors at the
>   application level by assigning a Cursor to the Current property

Comment: Changing it like that causes the cursor to revert back to a plain old pointer almost immediately.

Comment: Another possibility is _Application.UseWaitCursor = true_ then false

Comment: Trying "UseWaitCursor" won't even compile for me; I get, "'System.Windows.Forms.Cursor' does not contain a definition for 'UseWaitCursor' ..."

Comment: Application.UseWaitCursor, sorry

Comment: Okay, this is really bizarro - the wait cursor begins spinning only AFTER the logic has completed now!

Comment: Not sure what happens there. I would try to put a Thread.Delay(10000) commenting out the code between the Cursor settings just to check if the problem is somewhere in the code logic between the Cursor setting.

Comment: I finally did get it working with Application.UseWaitCursor